# Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'disnake'

Tags: python, disnake

Решил написать нового бота на [disnake](/questions/tagged/disnake) и для проверки библиотек написал простые `event`-ы на вывод информации, что бот запущен и команду на вывод сообщения о подключении к серверу

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    channel = bot.get_channel(id)
    await channel.send('Привет! Я только что подключился к серверу!')

bot.run("Нема")
```

Проблема в этих двух строчках
`import disnake` и `from disnake.ext import commands`
На эти строчки выдает ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'disnake'`

[image: то что он выдает]

Пишу код в VSC на ОС macOS Catalina 10.15.7
Все библиотеки нужные установлены

Comment: **Все библиотеки нужные установлены**. а можете привести доказательство данного? С какой версии Python запускаетесь? Выведите список установленных библиотек инструментом, которым вы ставили данную библиотеку, проверьте что данный инструмент запускается с той же версии Python, что и ваш код